# How to pass selected parameters to a python constructor

Tags: python, constructor

I have an initializer like this:

```
def __init__(self, options=None, rinse=True, algorithm="foo"):
   if options is not None:
      self.options = options
   else: 
      self.create_default()

   if (rinse==False): #would mean rinse parameter was passed
      self.options.rinse = rinse
   if (algorithm!="foo"): #would mean algorithm parameter was passed
      self.options.algorithm = algorithm
```

I would like to be able to call the above in several ways. Below are some examples:

```
a = MyClass() #nothing was passed
a = MyClass(rinse: False) #only rinse parameter was passed
a = MyClass(algorithm: "bar") #only algorithm parameter was passed
a = MyClass(options, rinse, algorithm) #pass all three arguments
```

**Question**

How can I structure this initializer such a way that I can pass selective arguments.

Comment: `def __init__` is not a constructor, it's an initializer magic method which serves to set initial values, not to construct the actual instance.

Comment: Read about positional and keyword arguments

Comment: This may help you. 
https://pythontips.com/2013/08/04/args-and-kwargs-in-python-explained/

Comment: The approach you have now works. Other than the syntax error.

Comment: Apologies for a bad question. I should have read the difference before posting. I believe `def __init__ (self, options=None, **kwargs)` will work best for me. This way I can call by `MyClass(rinse=False, algorithm='foobar')`. I'll have to change the `if/else` blocks inside but thats ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to change your examples to use equals signs instead of colons, your `__init__` should work fine as-is:

```
a = MyClass() #nothing was passed
a = MyClass(rinse= False) #only rinse parameter was passed
a = MyClass(algorithm= "bar") #only algorithm parameter was passed
a = MyClass(options, rinse, algorithm) #pass all three arguments
```